# Initialising Neon-Animated-Pages

Tags: polymer

I am new to Polymer and I am struggeling to make a nice approach of an initialisation of a neon-animated wizard.

In my interface, the user should be able to register in different steps:

1. General Information (E-Mail, Username,...)
2. Personal Information (First Name, Last Name, etc...)
3. Other stuff...

Each time the user finishes one step, the wizard "slides" to the next step (with a neon-animation).

My problem is that I don't know how to reset the wizard when the user leaves the registration and comes back in. For instance, if I'm on step 2, leave the registration page and press the button"Register" again, the user is still on step 2. I want it to be step 1. It only works if I refresh the browser Window (Pressing F5).

I hope I could make it clear, posting code would just make it more difficult in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the register button is clicked, set the "selected" property of the "neon-animated-pages" to 0 (if you didn't set "attrToSelected") or to the value of your first page, that will transition to the first page.
Here's a quick example
http://jsbin.com/sulitowuge/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: This was my first approach. I think it should be somehow possible to refresh the page locally. I will mark this as answer for the time being.

Comment: What do you mean with locally? I mean, the viewable "page" should update whenever the selected property is changed

Comment: Hi Alan, I want the selected property to be 0 every time I open the page containing the neon-animated-pages.

Comment: @ElMac just set the selected property's initial value to 0 (or to the value of your initial page), like `<neon-animated-pages selected="0"> ...`